# Change the background color of a SwiftUI List before the list gets loaded in

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I'm working on a SwiftUI project and I'm having trouble with a list having a different background color than the rest of my screen. Specifically, the background of the list placeholder (i.e. before the list gets loaded in). Here is what I have so far:

```
    var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
        ZStack {
            gradient
                .opacity(0.35)
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            
            VStack {
                Text("Search For Breweries")
                    .font(.system(.title3, design: .rounded))
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                
                TextField("Search by Name", text: $brewSearch)
                    .frame(width: 300, height: 50.0)
                    .textInputAutocapitalization(.never)
                    .disableAutocorrection(true)
                    .border(.primary)
                    .cornerRadius(3.0)
                    .padding()
                    .onChange(of: brewSearch) { newValue in
                        brewSearch = newValue
                        Task.init(operation: {
                            if !newValue.isEmpty {
                                self.networkManager.fetchDataBySearch(name: newValue.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "_"))
                            }
                        })
                    }
                
                HStack(alignment: .center) {
                    ZStack {
                        Capsule()
                            .fill(Color("Brown"))
                        Capsule()
                            .fill(.black.opacity(0.15))
                            .padding(8)
                        HStack {
                            Text("Search by your location")
                            Image(systemName: "location")
                                .font(.system(size: 24, weight: .bold))
                        }
                    } //: Button ZStack
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .frame(width: 300, height: 80)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        locationManager.requestAuthorization(always: true)
                        guard let latitude = CLLocationManager().location?.coordinate.latitude else {return}
                        guard let longitude = CLLocationManager().location?.coordinate.longitude else {return}
                        networkManager.fetchDataByLocation(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
                        
                        }
                    } //: HStack
                            List {
                                ForEach(networkManager.breweries) { brewery in
                                    // All the list items that will get loaded in
                            }
                        }
                            .background(.clear)
                            .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Once the list gets loaded in, the background becomes the same as the rest of the screen, but before anything loads in, the section where the list will appear is white. I'll attach some screenshots of what I'm talking about:

[[image: After the List is loaded]
[[image: Before the list is loaded]

How can I change it so the white area where the list will go is the same color of the rest of the screen? Right now I don't care about each list item's background color, just the background for where the list will go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try this approach:

```
 List {
      ForEach(networkManager.breweries) { brewery in
          // All the list items that will get loaded in
      }
  }.blendMode(networkManager.breweries.isEmpty ? .destinationOver : .normal)
```

Comment: This did it! Thank you so much! I've never heard of .blendMode, I'll have to check that out more.